# How can I create a dictionary for Mac OS X 10.8?

Tags: xcode, macos, dictionary

Dictionary seems to be several versions ahead of the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/DictionaryServicesProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006152-CH1-DontLinkElementID_23) (2007).  I found a [good blog post](http://nagpals.com/posts/mac-dictionaries/) about it, but everything seems different now.  I installed Xcode (including the command line tools) but nothing is where it's supposed to be (e.g. Developer does not get created and there is no Dictionary Development Kit).  I would like to make a pretty complicated dictionary, so I'd like to make this work instead of converting file types.

Where is `Developer/Extras/Dictionary Development Kit` now?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Everything that was in /Developer is now embedded in the Xcode.app folder. Some items were not brought over by default and must be downloaded manually from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

You want the "Auxiliary Tools" for your version of Xcode.

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer. It awards you reputation as well!